# what's wrong with this XOR encryption?

Tags: encryption, xor

i'm trying to find out the key of a xor encryption but something seems be wrong.

the ecrypted file begins with this hex string:
78DF2B983C9428942894892CD8D6CFF4F8942895289428952894319428949BFD8F0289089D068DC556C458C25D94289428942894289428942894289428942894289428942894289C289428942894289428942894289428942894289428942894289428942894289428942894289428942894289428942894289428942894289428942894289428942894289428942894..

i know this is a zip comressed file. the zip header structure is something like:
504B0304140000000800CC898C459C47ECC9DA8350002DC06400120000003937373048442D56312E30302E352E676E78 (https://users.cs.jmu.edu/buchhofp/forensics/formats/pkzip.html)

the first 4 bytes of a zip header is always the signature:
504B0304, after xor this with the ecrypted hex, i get: 2894289c

but 2894289c seems to be wrong, why? look at the encrypted hex string..
there's lot of '2894' hex values in the content..these must be decrypted '0000', so is '2894' the right key?

now, i xor the encrypted zip header signature with the key '2894'
78DF2B98 xor 28942894 => 504b030c
pretty strange, because the last hex value is '0c' but it must be '04'!

what is my fault?

(sorry for my english)

Comment: Why do you expect all zero bytes? This seems to depend on the contents of the file. Could well be length encodings etc.

Comment: well, xor the encrypted with decrypted hex:
78df2b983c9428942894(enc)
xor
504b0304140000000000(plain)
=> 2894289c289428942894

so, the key should be '2894' but it isn't